# UIToolbar causes lots of output warning in output window after I click on textfield. Swift 5.0

Tags: swift

I have 2 textfields in my page(`ViewController`). I have added an `UIToolbar` like below:

(By the way, I have removed necessary code)

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

lazy var firstTextfield : UITextField =
    {
        let otextfield = UITextField()
        return otextfield
}()

lazy var secondTextfield : UITextField =
    {
        let otextfield = UITextField()
        return otextfield
}()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstTextfield.delegate = self
    secondTextfield.delegate = self
    add_a_tool_bar_feature()
}

func add_a_tool_bar_feature()
{
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let closeKeyboard = UIBarButtonItem(title: "an action", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done , target: self, action: nil)

    let textfieldTitle = UIBarButtonItem(title:"(field name)" , style:UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: nil)

    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    toolBar.setItems([textfieldTitle,flexibleSpace,klavyeyiKapatTamam], animated: false)

    firstTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    secondTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
}
```

I see lots of `output` after I click on any `textfield` after I run the application. Let me share them.

**I don't get any warning if I don't call `add_a_tool_bar_feature()` method in `viewDidLoad`. That means UIToolbar causes all these output warnings, right? How can I get rid of this?**

```
2020-04-12 03:02:11.553950+0300 abcApp[19290:9332074] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using 25698_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

2020-04-12 03:02:11.593727+0300 abcApp[19290:9332074] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x2815899a0 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x100a5e5d0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815e1a90 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x100a5ed30]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x100a5e5d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815e1ae0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x100a5ed30.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x100a5e5d0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815885f0 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x100a943a0'(alan ismi)']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a93e90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281588640 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x100a943a0'(alan ismi)']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a93e90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281589180 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x280fc81c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x100a93e90.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281589310 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x280fc81c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x100a96ca0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281589360 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a93e90]-(0)-[UIView:0x100a96b30]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815893b0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x100a96b30]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a96ca0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815e1900 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x280fc81c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x100a5ed30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815e19a0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x280fc81c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x100a5ed30 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281588640 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x100a943a0'(alan ismi)']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a93e90 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2020-04-12 03:02:11.594781+0300 abcApp[19290:9332074] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x2815899a0 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x100a5e5d0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815e1a90 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x100a5ed30]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x100a5e5d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815e1ae0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x100a5ed30.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x100a5e5d0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281588dc0 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x100a97ae0'Klavyeyi Kapat']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a96ca0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281588e10 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x100a97ae0'Klavyeyi Kapat']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a96ca0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281589180 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x280fc81c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x100a93e90.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281589310 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x280fc81c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x100a96ca0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281589360 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a93e90]-(0)-[UIView:0x100a96b30]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815893b0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x100a96b30]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a96ca0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815e1900 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x280fc81c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x100a5ed30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2815e19a0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x280fc81c0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x100a5ed30 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281588e10 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x100a97ae0'Klavyeyi Kapat']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x100a96ca0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your toolbar has no size. Give it some sort of reasonable frame before populating it, and do not call `sizeToFit`.